# How to handle button touch inside the UICollectionviewCell or UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This is a problem that I always stay in dilemma when I creating cells.

Let's say I have a custom cell (`PlaceCell`) which I'm using in different controllers and collectionviews. It has a label which identify the place name (`PlaceNameLabel`) and will navigate to place detail when user taps on it.

This doesn't matter controller, collectionviews or wherever cell is used, this is independent of where it is used.

So I have to put the `PlaceNameLabel's UITapGestureRecognizer` code inside the `PlaceCell` class.

```
class PlaceCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var placeName: UILabel!
     override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        initEventListeners()
    }

    func initEventListeners() {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
                   action: #selector(handlePlaceNameTouch))
    }

    func handlePlaceNameTouch() {
        // I have to push a new view controller here
    }
}
```

But if I want to push the place detail view controller I need to access the controller. If I want to access the controller I have two options and this is where I stay in dilemma, I have read lots of SO questions answers most of them suggest the second option, but I think the first one is better approach. But I don't know if it's problem to reference the controller inside the cell.

Could you please share your opinion or any other method to handle this problem?

## FIRST OPTION

Referencing the controller inside the cell,

```
extension MyController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlaceCell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCell
        cell.controller = self
        return cell
    }
}

class PlaceCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     var controller: UIViewController?
     @IBOutlet weak var placeName: UILabel!
     override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        initEventListeners()
    }

    func initEventListeners() {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
                   action: #selector(handlePlaceNameTouch))
    }

    func handlePlaceNameTouch() {
        controller.navigationController.pushViewController(PlaceDetailController(), 
                                             animated: true)
    }
}
```

## SECOND OPTION

Create protocol and delegate, pass event to controller and do whatever you want,
(I think this is not well, because action is about the cell and I have to create protocol function multiple times because I use this Cell in different Controllers)

```
protocol PlaceCellDelegate {
  func handlePlaceNameTouch()
}

class PlaceCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var delegate: PlaceCellDelegate?
    @IBOutlet weak var placeName: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        initEventListeners()
    }

    func initEventListeners() {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
                           action: #selector(handlePlaceNameTouch))
    }

    func handlePlaceNameTouch() {
        delegate?.handlePlaceNameTouch()
    }
}

extension MyController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, PlaceCellDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlaceCell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func handlePlaceNameTouch() {
          self.navigationController.pushViewController(PlaceDetailController(), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You no need to handle specially to cell selection. No need to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` or no need implement your own protocol to detect cell selection.

**`UICollectionView` and `UITableView` has its own protocols for that.**

Cell selection delegate for `UICollectionView` - **`UICollectionViewDelegate`** protocol

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Cell selection delegate for `UITableView` - **`UITableViewDelegate`** protocol

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Confirm `protocol` & set `delegate` on your `UIViewController`

```
class viewcontroller : UICollectionViewDelegate {
   @IBOutlet weak collectionView: UICollectionView!

   func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       collectionView.delegate = self
   }
}
```

And implement the protocol method inside a view controller, which I mentioned above.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   //indexPath - Index path of selected cell.

   // Add you cell selection logic here. 
}
```

This method will be triggered when you tap on the cell. Inside this method fetch the model from datasource array. and navigate to detail view based on which cell (model) selected by user.

Comment: no actually, I don't need cell selection, PlaceCell also has other buttons, labels etc. I need to handle view click inside the cell, but thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

While both your options are possible, if you are hesitating I would recommend the delegate approach as it is a more "swifty" way of doing it and makes the cell reusable.

Here is a third option using an onTapHandler which doesn't use the delegate pattern and still keeps the cell reusable:

```
class PlaceCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     // A handler called when the button is pressed
     var onTapHandler: (() -> Void)?

     @IBOutlet weak var placeName: UILabel!

     override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        initEventListeners()
    }

    func initEventListeners() {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
                   action: #selector(handlePlaceNameTouch))
    }

    func handlePlaceNameTouch() {

        // Make sure the handler exists, else...
        guard let handler = self.onTapHandler else {
            return
        }

        // Execute handler
        handler()
    }
}
```

You would then use it like so:

```
extension MyController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, PlaceCellDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlaceCell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCell

        cell.onTapHandler = { [weak self] in
            self?.navigationController.pushViewController(PlaceDetailController(), animated: true)
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for third method, let me ask you what will I do If I use the cell in another Controller, I will write the .onTapHandler everytime I use it. That is redundancy.

Comment: @ocanal I see how you could think it's redundant to write the handler in every controller. But given that the cell subclasses UIView and not UIViewController, in a proper MVC setting it should only act as a view and by such delegate all logic to its parent UIViewController. By doing so you make it reusable as the UIViewController will uniquely decide what happens when it's tapped.